# pandas: Aggregate based on start/end date

Tags: python, pandas

It is actually a de-aggregation because I have a dataset structured this way:

```
id  type   first_year   last_year
A   t1     2009         2014
A   t1     2010         2015
B   t1     2007         2009
B   t2     2008         2011
```

But I need to aggregate by id/year and have overlapping start/end entries.

Data is in a pandas data frame like so:

```
test_frame = pd.DataFrame([['A','t1',2009,2014],
                       ['A','t1',2010,2015],
                       ['B','t1',2007,2009],
                       ['B','t2',2008,2011]],
                      columns = ['id','type','first_year','last_year'])
```

I'm hoping to get data returned in a few different ways:

```
id  year  count
A   2009  1
A   2010  2
A   2011  2
...
B   2007  1
B   2008  2
B   2009  1
```

And perhaps like this:

```
id  year  type    count
A   2009  t1      1
A   2010  t1      2
A   2011  t1      2
...
B   2007  t1      1
B   2008  t1      1
B   2008  t2      1
B   2009  t2      1
B   2010  t2      1
```

This basically works for the 1st method, but as you can imagine it is pretty slow using itertuples for a large dataset.  Any more pandas-ic way?

```
out_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['id','type','year'])
for rows in test_frame.itertuples():
    for year in range(int(rows[3]),int(rows[4])):
        d2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [rows[1]],'year': [year]},columns = ['id','year'])
        out_frame = out_frame.append(d2)
output1 = out_frame.groupby(['id','year'])['year'].count()
output1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html):

```
import pandas as pd

test_frame = pd.DataFrame([['A','t1',2009,2014],
                       ['A','t1',2010,2015],
                       ['B','t1',2007,2009],
                       ['B','t2',2008,2011]],
                      columns = ['id','type','first_year','last_year'])

print test_frame
  id type  first_year  last_year
0  A   t1        2009       2014
1  A   t1        2010       2015
2  B   t1        2007       2009
3  B   t2        2008       2011

#stack df, drop and rename column year
test_frame = test_frame.set_index(['id','type'], append=True).stack().reset_index(level=[1,2,3])
test_frame = test_frame.drop('level_3', axis=1).rename(columns={0:'year'})
#convert year to datetime
test_frame['year'] = pd.to_datetime(test_frame['year'], format="%Y")
print test_frame
  id type       year
0  A   t1 2009-01-01
0  A   t1 2014-01-01
1  A   t1 2010-01-01
1  A   t1 2015-01-01
2  B   t1 2007-01-01
2  B   t1 2009-01-01
3  B   t2 2008-01-01
3  B   t2 2011-01-01
```

```
#resample and fill missing data 
out_frame = test_frame.groupby(test_frame.index).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('year').resample('1AS', how='first',fill_method='ffill')).reset_index(level=1)
print out_frame
        year id type
0 2009-01-01  A   t1
0 2010-01-01  A   t1
0 2011-01-01  A   t1
0 2012-01-01  A   t1
0 2013-01-01  A   t1
0 2014-01-01  A   t1
1 2010-01-01  A   t1
1 2011-01-01  A   t1
1 2012-01-01  A   t1
1 2013-01-01  A   t1
1 2014-01-01  A   t1
1 2015-01-01  A   t1
2 2007-01-01  B   t1
2 2008-01-01  B   t1
2 2009-01-01  B   t1
3 2008-01-01  B   t2
3 2009-01-01  B   t2
3 2010-01-01  B   t2
3 2011-01-01  B   t2

#convert to year
out_frame['year'] = out_frame['year'].dt.year
```

```
output1 = out_frame.groupby(['id','year', 'type'])['year'].count().reset_index(name='count')
print output1
   id  year type  count
0   A  2009   t1      1
1   A  2010   t1      2
2   A  2011   t1      2
3   A  2012   t1      2
4   A  2013   t1      2
5   A  2014   t1      2
6   A  2015   t1      1
7   B  2007   t1      1
8   B  2008   t1      1
9   B  2008   t2      1
10  B  2009   t1      1
11  B  2009   t2      1
12  B  2010   t2      1
13  B  2011   t2      1
```

```
output2 = out_frame.groupby(['id','year'])['year'].count().reset_index(name='count')
print output2
   id  year  count
0   A  2009      1
1   A  2010      2
2   A  2011      2
3   A  2012      2
4   A  2013      2
5   A  2014      2
6   A  2015      1
7   B  2007      1
8   B  2008      2
9   B  2009      2
10  B  2010      1
11  B  2011      1
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based on expanding the year columns using a PeriodIndex. Then taking this period range and *stacking* (rotating) it so that it creates multi-level index.

```
def expand_period(row):
   "Creates a series from first to last year and appends it to the row"
   p = pd.period_range(row["first_year"], row["last_year"], freq="A")
   return row.append(p.to_series()).drop(["first_year","last_year"])

#original data frame
tf = pd.DataFrame([['A','t1',2009,2014],
                   ['A','t1',2010,2015],
                   ['B','t1',2007,2009],
                   ['B','t2',2008,2011]],
                  columns = ['id','type','first_year','last_year'])

#Drop the year columns but replace them with expanded series
tfexpanded = tf.apply(expand_period, 1).set_index(["id","type"])
#Rotate the axis so that you have a 3 level index
tfindexed = tfexpanded.stack()
#This is not necessary but improves readability when watching the output
tfindexed[:] = 1
#Group-By as you did before
answer = tfindexed.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).count()
```

Of course, the whole thing can be simplified using lambdas and chained methods.