# Performance issue turning rows with start - end into a dataframe with TimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a large dataset where each line represents the value of a certain type (think  a sensor) for a time interval (between start and end).
It looks like this:

```
    start       end    type value
2015-01-01  2015-01-05  1   3
2015-01-06  2015-01-08  1   2
2015-01-05  2015-01-08  3   3
2015-01-13  2015-01-16  2   1
```

I want to turn it into a daily time-indexed frame like this:

```
day       type  value
2015-01-01  1   3
2015-01-02  1   3
2015-01-03  1   3
2015-01-04  1   3
2015-01-05  1   3
2015-01-06  1   2
2015-01-07  1   2
2015-01-08  1   2
2015-01-05  3   3
2015-01-16  3   3
2015-01-07  3   3
2015-01-08  3   3
2015-01-13  2   1
2015-01-14  2   1
2015-01-15  2   1
2015-01-16  2   1
```

(Note that we cannot make any assumption regarding the interval: they *should* be contiguous and non-overlapping but we cannot guarantee that)

Based on these Stack Overflow answers [1] ([DataFrame resample on date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484458/dataframe-resample-on-date-ranges?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) [2] ([pandas: Aggregate based on start/end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187444/pandas-aggregate-based-on-start-end-date)), there seem to exist two methods: one around itertuples, one around melt (2 above used stack/unstack but it is similar to melt).
Let us compare them for performance.

```
# Creating a big enough dataframe
date_range = pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2015,1,1), end=dt.datetime(2019,12,31), freq='4D')
to_concat = []
for val in range(1,50):
    frame_tmp = pd.DataFrame()
    frame_tmp['start'] = date_range
    frame_tmp['end'] = frame_tmp['start']+ dt.timedelta(3)
    frame_tmp['type'] = val
    frame_tmp['value'] = np.random.randint(1, 6, frame_tmp.shape[0])
    to_concat.append(frame_tmp)
df = pd.concat(to_concat, ignore_index=True)

# Method 1 
def method_1(df):
    df1 = (pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,
                                pd.date_range(r.start,
                                              r.end,
                                              freq='D'))
                      for r in df.itertuples()])) \
        .reset_index()
    df1.columns = ['start_2', 'idx']

    df2 = df1.set_index('idx').join(df).reset_index(drop=True)

    return df2.set_index('start_2')

df_method_1=df.groupby(['type']).apply(method_1)

# Method 2
df_tmp= df.reset_index()
df1 = (df_tmp.melt(df_tmp.columns.difference(['start','end']),
          ['start', 'end'],
          value_name='current_time')
  )
df_method_2 = df1.set_index('current_time').groupby('index', group_keys=False)\
.resample('D').ffill()
```

With `%%timeit` in Jupyter, method 1 takes ~8s and method 2 takes ~25s for the dataframe defined as example. This is way too slow as the real dataset that I am dealing with is much bigger than this. On that dataframe, method 1 takes ~20 minutes.

Do you have any idea on how to make this faster?

Comment: I can't run your code, what is `date_range` in `frame_tmp['start'] = date_range`?

Comment: Good catch! I have updated the code. Thank you @Ben.T

Comment: What is `df_tmp`? Also, since you say 'we cannot make any assumption regarding the interval', I assume you want to expand the specified readings (even if they overlap or have gaps), rather than looking up each day of the year among the available readings. Is that right?

Comment: Good catch! just a .reset_index(). I have updated the code.
And yes, I want to expand the specific readings, as this would then allow me to do any kind of check in a generic way. @MatthiasFripp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about 1.7 times faster than your `method_1` and a little tidier:

```
df_expand = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    (
        (d, r.type, r.value) 
        for r in df.itertuples()
        for d in pd.date_range(start=r.start, end=r.end, freq='D')
    ),
    columns=['day', 'type', 'row']
)
```

You can get about 7 times faster by creating your own date range instead of calling `pd.date_range()`:

```
one_day = dt.timedelta(1)
df_expand = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    (
        (r.start + i * one_day, r.type, r.value) 
        for r in df.itertuples()
        for i in range(int((r.end-r.start)/one_day)+1)
    ),
    columns=['day', 'type', 'row']
)
```

Or you can get up to 24 times faster by using numpy's `arange` function to generate the dates:

```
one_day = dt.timedelta(1)
df_expand = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    (
        (d, r.type, r.value) 
        for r in df.itertuples()
        for d in np.arange(r.start.date(), r.end.date()+one_day, dtype='datetime64[D]')
    ),
    columns=['day', 'type', 'row']
)
```

I couldn't resist adding one more that is a little more than twice as fast as the last one. Unfortunately, it's a lot harder to read. This groups the readings based on how many days they span ('dur'), then uses vectorized numpy operations to expand each group in a single batch.

```
def expand_group(g):
    dur = g.dur.iloc[0] # how many days for each reading in this group?
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'day': (g.start.values[:,None] + np.timedelta64(1, 'D') * np.arange(dur)).ravel(),
        'type': np.repeat(g.type.values, dur),
        'value': np.repeat(g.value.values, dur),
    })
# take all readings with the same duration and process them together using vectorized code
df_expand = (
    df.assign(dur=(df['end']-df['start']).dt.days + 1)
    .groupby('dur').apply(expand_group)
    .reset_index('dur', drop=True)
)
```

**Update:** Responding to your comment, below is a simplified version of the vectorized approach, which is faster and easier to read. Instead of using the `groupby` step, this makes a single matrix as wide as the longest reading, then filters out the unneeded entries. This should be pretty efficient unless the maximum duration for your readings is much longer than the average. With the test dataframe (all readings lasting 4 days), this is about 15x faster than the `groupby` solution and about 700x faster than `method_1`.

```
dur = (df['end']-df['start']).max().days + 1
df_expand = pd.DataFrame({
    'day': (
        df['start'].values[:,None] + np.timedelta64(1, 'D') * np.arange(dur)
    ).ravel(),
    'type': np.repeat(df['type'].values, dur),
    'value': np.repeat(df['value'].values, dur),
    'end': np.repeat(df['end'].values, dur),
})
df_expand = df_expand.loc[df_expand['day']<=df_expand['end'], 'day':'value']
```

Comment: That is such an incredible speed-up!
I have checked on the real datasets which inspired that question. That part of the process is now taking less ~25, when it used to be well above 20 minutes. 
Thank you so so much!

Comment: @Phik, just to let you know, in my third method, I originally didn't account for the fact that `np.arange()` is not inclusive on the upper end, so it omitted the last date of each reading. I've fixed it now.

Comment: actually on my real datasets, your vectorized method (#4) is 6.5 times faster than #3! That is incredible! Again thank you so much.
I am still wondering if it would be possible to do without the groupby, have you tried anything like this?

Comment: @Phik, The trick with the numpy vectorized code is that it constructs a matrix with one row for every start day and one column for every day in the measurement window. This is only possible if each batch has the same length of measurement window (to make a regular matrix), which is why it groups by `dur`. But maybe it’s possible to use the maximum duration and fill in nulls beyond the dur for each reading, then drop them later. Or you could repeatedly add entries for all rows with dur >10, >9, >8, etc., then sort them back together. But that would probably be slower than `groupby`.

Comment: @Phik, You were right, eliminating the `groupby` saves a lot of time, and it also makes the code easier to understand. See the new version above.

Comment: On my real dataset, this latest method is a bit slower ( ~20%) than the latest groupby one (#4). There are some 'dur' that span a month but the typical 'dur' is a week. So creating ~4 times too many rows and filtering then out afterwards is probably what makes it slower(as you hinted two comments ago). This is a limit of the fake dataframe I created for this SO question, but I am sure it will be useful to others. 
Again thank you very much, I have learned a lot from this question!

Comment: @Phik, Yeah, that sounds like a problem. You might try the final method in two passes, one for all readings that are 7 days or less, and one for the longer readings. It may improve the speed if there are only a few long readings. But that is similar to doing a mini-groupby on your own, so it may not be much faster, and the extra complexity would be annoying.