# Create a python dataframe by flatten two columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
zip      season   season_start_date   season_end_date
zip1     winter   2015-11-25          2016-03-09
```

I need kind to flatten the date between the start and end dates.
I expect the output like this:

```
zip       season   date   
zip1      winter   2015-11-25
zip1      winter   2015-11-26
.
.
zip1      winter   2016-03-09
```

How could I realize in a more elegant way?

```
data = {"zip":["zip1","zip1"],
    "season":["s6","s6"],
    "season_start_date": ["2011-01-01","2011-01-01"], 
    "season_end_date" : ["2012-01-05","2012-01-05"]
   }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since I didn't have time to finish the solution i was writting, [here is an useful concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274267/print-all-day-dates-between-two-dates/7274316) I was using as reference :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance issue turning rows with start - end into a dataframe with TimeIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747359/performance-issue-turning-rows-with-start-end-into-a-dataframe-with-timeindex)

Comment: That's what I need. Thanks for the elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

Row_to_split = df.loc[1]
Season = Row_to_split['season']
Start_Date = datetime.strptime(Row_to_split['season_start_date']', '%Y-%m-%d')
End_Date = datetime.strptime(Row_to_split['season_end_date']', '%Y-%m-%d')
# initialize new_df 
for i in range((End_Date - Start_Date).days+1):
    new_df.loc[i] = [season, (Start_Date+timedelta(i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]
```

Does that do what you wanted? I wasn't sure if the zip column was an index, but it should be apparent how to insert that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to generate a DataFrame from each row, and then concat them together:

```
res = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({
        'zip': r.zip, 'season': r.season, 'date': pd.DatetimeIndex(
            start=r.season_start_date, end=r.season_end_date, freq='D'
        )
    }) for _, r in data.iterrows()
], sort=False)
```